# Not able to compile apk with GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating an app which requires me send push notification to my users...
I am using the example from the below link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

The error I am getting is

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library C:\Users\VLSI-9\Desktop\Android\AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\7.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all" to force usage
```

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidhive.pushnotifications"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

I have installed all extras.

Comment: I suggest you include only required part of Play Lib, GCM reference is enough compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'

Comment: already tried with com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0
not working

Comment: You have an answer already, increment your minSdkVersion to 9

Comment: what the hell is compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:8' ?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 22

Comment: that is giving error at 
C:\AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.0.0\res\values-v21\values.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.

Comment: You are using old version of support-v4, the latest is 22.2.0

Comment: changed to compliesdkversion 22
Error:Cause: failed to find target 22 : C:\Users\VLSI-9\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>
again and again...i have installed it ones...then also its showing like that

Comment: update your sdk version, build tools and support library repository with support lib as well.

Comment: done some changes now..
its showing
Error:(12, 30) error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist

Comment: Update your code in question

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `build.gradle` and change your app's `minSdkVersion` to `9`

Comment: i use eclipse, thats why

Comment: Error:(8, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library C:\AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\7.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Error:(8, 5) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library C:AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\7.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all" to force usage

Answer (score 0):

open the manifest of the Google-play-service and check if the minimum SDK is 9, if it's try to downgrade it by change to 8 and rebuild it, if it's not success change the minimum SDK of your application to 9 and rebuild it.

Comment: tried to change in following directory
C:\Android\AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\7.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml

everytime  i try to comple it, it get replaced by minimum sdk 9

Comment: eclipse? or android studio?

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: did you change also the gradle to 9?

Comment: yeah
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidhive.pushnotifications"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms.gcm:play-services:+'
}

Comment: now its saying

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms.gcm:play-services:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/gcm/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/gcm/play-services/

Comment: file:/C:/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/gcm/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/gcm/play-services/
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/gcm/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/gcm/play-services/
     Required by:
         AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM:app:unspecified